# Flutter: Crashlytics Plugin throwing Bad State error on crash

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, crashlytics

I have followed the steps on https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics to install the plugin. However, when I force a crash using `Crashlytics.instance.crash();` I get the following error:

```
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following StateError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Bad state: Error thrown by Crashlytics plugin

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Crashlytics.crash (package:firebase_crashlytics/src/firebase_crashlytics.dart:54:5)
#1      _ProfileScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:genchi_app/screens/profile_screen.dart:93:44)
#2      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:779:19)
#3      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:862:36)
#4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
```

Why is it not catching the error and showing the following?

`flutter: Flutter error caught by Crashlytics plugin:`

EDIT:

Android crashes are being sent to the console, but iOS is not. Neither android or iOS show that the Crashlytics plugin is catching the errors during development.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are performing a force crash?

Comment: Simply in a flat button within the ```onPressed: () { Crashlytics.instance.crash(); }```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got to know about your problem.

What you are getting is exactly what you are doing in your code. I have checked the [firebase_crashLytics.dart line 54](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_crashlytics/lib/src/firebase_crashlytics.dart)(see code below)

```
void crash() {
    throw StateError('Error thrown by Crashlytics plugin');
  }
```

So the crash function you are calling throws the error because it is meant to throw error.

Comment: I see. But why do I not get the text: ```flutter: Flutter error caught by Crashlytics plugin:
// OR if you use recordError for runZoned:
flutter: Error caught by Crashlytics plugin <recordError>:
// Exception, context, information, and stack trace in debug mode
// OR if not in debug mode:
flutter: Error reported to Crashlytics.```

Comment: It appears my android crashes are still appearing as "non fatal" on the dashboard. However, none of the iOS ones are being submitted.

Comment: That's something different then the question you have asked. You can post it as a new one.

Comment: Either way, why is the above text not appearing within the console? That should be happening if the crashes are being caught.

Comment: I have copied exactly what is written in the package installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Flutter catches a lot of errors in debug mode, and prints them on the console without rethrowing them. So the method `FlutterError.onError` is not called in this cases.

I solved this problem by disabling the "Flutter Structured Errors" feature as suggested [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48972).

For VS Code I just added the following line in `.vscode/settings.json`:

```
"dart.flutterStructuredErrors": false
```